# Ĉu oni uzu "la" aŭ "mia" kiam oni parolas pri siaj propraj korpopartoj?

Tags: word-usage, article, possessive

Ĉu oni uzu "la" aŭ "mia" kiam oni parolas pri siaj propraj korpopartoj? Diversaj lingvoj havas diversajn kutimojn rilate al ĉi tio. En la angla oni uzas posesivon sed en la sveda oni uzas definitivon. Jen ekzemploj:

- Mia/La dorso doloras al mi.
- Mi brosis miajn/la dentojn.
- Ŝi rompis sian/la brakon.

Kio ĝustas en Esperanto?

Answer (score 4):

Ambaŭ manieroj eblas, sed mi rekomendas la uzon de "la" en tiuj okazoj.

Paranteze, ankaŭ la angla foje uzas la artikolon.

- He punched me in the gut. // Li pugnobatis min en la ventro.

Se ni dirus - he punched me in my gut // li pugnobatis min en mia ventro - la "my/mia" ŝajnas superflua. Estas same pri aliaj esprimoj.

- Mi brosas (al mi) la dentojn.
- La dorso doloras al mi.
- Ŝi rompis (al si) la brakon.

**Tio sekvas la principo de neceso kaj sufiĉo.** Ne necesas diri kies dentojn. Sufiĉas diri "la dentojn." (Ĉiuj jam scias.)

Mi ĵus faris rapidan serĉon en la Tekstaro por la sufiĉe malofta okazo de "mi" apud "genuoj" - kaj mi trovis esprimojn kaj kun "la" kaj kun "miaj." La esprimoj kun "miaj" ja klarigas pri kies genuoj temas. (Vidu "neceso kaj sufiĉo.")

Ekzemple:

- mi sur la genuoj vin petegis
- li sur la genuoj petu de vi pardonon
- ĉiuj falas antaŭ mi sur la genuojn

Kaj kontraste:

- **li** genuis antaŭ mi kaj ekprenis **miajn** genuojn kvazaŭ preĝante,
- Pro tio mi fleksas **miajn** genuojn antaŭ la Patro, (Ankaŭ "meine" en la germana biblio).
- lia mano kuŝis sur mia genuo,
- mi volonte prezentus mian genuon al la kisoj de ...

Kiam la genuoj ne estas tiuj de la aganto

- mi kuŝadis sur la genuoj de la plej altaj gesinjoro
- tuj kiam mi eksidis, [la hundo] saltis sur la genuojn kaj restis tie

Mi emas pensi ke tiu lasta frazo estas erara.

Answer (score 0):

En praktiko, oni uzas ambaŭ formojn. En mia gepatra lingvo oni uzas la difinitan artikolon, sed en Esperanto mi sisteme uzas posesivojn, ĉar ili donas pli mallongajn frazojn. Do

- *Mia dorso doloras* (superflue *min, al mi*) aŭ *la dorso doloras al mi.*
- *Mi brosis miajn dentojn* (atentu, ne *ŝ*) aŭ *mi brosis al mi la dentojn.*
- *Ŝi rompis sian brakon* (atentu refleksivon) aŭ *ŝi rompis al si la brakon,* kaj, laŭ tio, kio efektive okazis, ankaŭ *ŝia brako rompiĝis* estas ebla.

Mi klopodis gugli tiujn kaj similajn frazojn, por iom mezuri la relativan oftecon, kaj ricevis kontraŭdirajn rezultojn. Do ambaŭ formoj bonas, kaj nur pli detalaj studoj povas diri, kiu estas pli ofta (kio en si mem montras, ke la oftecoj ne multe malsamas).